# Using Git and Subversion together in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: git, svn, intellij-idea

I have imported both Git and SVN project in my IntelliJ IDEA workspace and they communicate with each other. The issue I am facing is I can't track local changes for both Git and SVN (Under Version Control Tab). I can see local changes only for SVN. The weird thing is I can still see the Git log under the Log tab of Version Control.

How can I see changes for both SVN and Git together? Or if I can see only one at a time , how can I change it to Git?

Comment: Did you configure 2 different mappings in Version Control Settings, one for Git and one for Subversion?

Comment: @CrazyCoder - No! Configuration was missing for Git. I added it manually. Somehow it was there for subversion automatically. It's working! :-) Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add both Subversion and Git roots in IDE Version Control settings:

- [Associating a Directory with a Specific Version Control System](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/associating-a-directory-with-a-specific-version-control-system.html)

Comment: This doesn't work for me (Idea v 2017.1.5) because even if I add the same directories twice once with Git and once with Svn, the VCS dialog will show and commit to Subversion only. But I know it worked once (only) then never again. Maybe the IDE can check into both Git & Svn only when the exact same files are modified.

Comment: This worked having a folder that is already initialized from command line with svn and git. controls change to  VCS and push will push/commit to both repos.